# How do I handle self joins with decent_exposure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, self-join

I have a `Forum` model, whose instances can have many nested forums:

```
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :nested_forums,
           :class_name => 'Forum',
           :foreign_key => 'parent_forum_id',
           :dependent => :nullify

  belongs_to :parent_forum,
             :class_name => 'Forum'
end
```

My routes go like this:

```
# Standard resource routes
GET /forums/:id                          =>  'forums#show'
# ...
GET  /forums/:forum_id/nested_forums/new =>  'Forums/nested_forums#new'
POST /forums/:forum_id/nested_forums     =>  'forums/nested_forums#create'
```

Now, in the controller:

```
class Forums::NestedForumsController < ApplicationController
  expose(:forum)                 # Will find with :forum_id
  expose(:nested_forums)         { forum.nested_forums }
  expose(:nested_forum)          # Main issue here
end
```

In the `:create` action, the code generated by the line `expose(:nested_forum)` will try to create a forum with `params[:nested_forum]`. This is an awkward situation since I'm using a self-join and there is no `NestedForum` model, and there doesn't seem to be a way to tell that to `decent_exposure`.

What would be a good way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my form, I had:

```
form_for nested_forum, :url => { ... } do |f|
  # ...
end
```

I added the `:as => :nested_forum` argument to the `form_for` method call and the form now stores the parameters in `params[:nested_forum]`, which solves my problem.